# Joomla 3 , change php else if for site link to something global

Tags: php, if-statement, joomla

i have a php elseif code that looks like that,

```
        <?php if ($item->getPrimaryImage()) :?>
        <img src="<?php echo $item->getPrimaryImage()->getSource(); ?>" class="sprocket-lists-image" alt="" />
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php echo $item->getText(); ?>
        <?php if ($item->getPrimaryLink()) : ?></br>

        <?php if ($item->getPrimaryLink()->getUrl() == "index.php/component/content/article?id=3200") : ?></br> 
        <a href="<?php echo $item->getPrimaryLink()->getUrl(); ?>" class="readon"><span><?php rc_e('READ_MORE'); ?></span></a>

        <?php elseif ($item->getPrimaryLink()->getUrl() == "index.php/component/content/article?id=1508") : ?></br>            
         <a href="<?php echo $item->getPrimaryLink()->getUrl(); ?>" class="readon"><span><?php rc_e('READ_MORE'); ?></span></a>

        <?php elseif ($item->getPrimaryLink()->getUrl() == "index.php/component/content/article?id=1840") : ?></br>            
         <a href="<?php echo $item->getPrimaryLink()->getUrl(); ?>" class="readon"><span><?php rc_e('READ_MORE'); ?></span></a> 

        <?php elseif ($item->getPrimaryLink()->getUrl() == "index.php/component/content/article?id=2541") : ?></br>            
         <a href="<?php echo $item->getPrimaryLink()->getUrl(); ?>" class="readon"><span><?php rc_e('READ_MORE'); ?></span></a>    

        <?php elseif ($item->getPrimaryLink()->getUrl() == "index.php/topmenu-1478/3350-2015-03-10-09-52-10") : ?></br>            
        <a href="<?php echo $item->getPrimaryLink()->getUrl(); ?>" class="readon"><span><?php rc_e('READ_MORE'); ?></span></a>       

        <?php elseif ($item->getPrimaryLink()->getUrl() == "index.php/component/content/article?id=3426") : ?></br>            
        <a href="<?php echo $item->getPrimaryLink()->getUrl(); ?>" class="readon"><span><?php rc_e('READ_MORE'); ?></span></a>      

        <?php elseif ($item->getPrimaryLink()->getUrl() == "index.php/component/content/article?id=3420") : ?></br>            
        <a href="<?php echo $item->getPrimaryLink()->getUrl(); ?>" class="readon"><span><?php rc_e('READ_MORE'); ?></span></a>                  

        <?php else : ?></br>

        <a href="<?php echo $item->getPrimaryLink()->getUrl(); ?>" class="modal" rel="{size: {x: 1024, y: 550}, handler:'iframe'}"><span><?php rc_e('READ_MORE'); ?></span></a>       

        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

the code is quite simple , that is

1. all the elseif have a link starting like == "index.php... etc,,, meaning that the readon button will open inside the website like _parent link WITHOUT the MODAL..
2. the last (case) else open all the rest links INSIDE THE MODAL

Question

You will notice that all the links on the elseif cases starting like "index.php/..,,, 
Is there is any way of coding to avoid all the elseif and having something global, meaning that will recognize the starting link "index.php/.. ?
You will notice that the action followed for the elseif

```
  <a href="<?php echo $item->getPrimaryLink()->getUrl(); ?>" class="readon"><span><?php rc_e('READ_MORE'); ?></span></a>
```

on all the cases is the same.

I need a piece of code that will understand-recognize the link starting "index.php/..
is this possible ?

Target

My target is that i do not want to use so many elseif every time a new link have to be added, and the code will take care it,, cause right now every time when i have to add a new image-banner that will link to an article inside the joomla site i have to hardcoded and add a new elseif like the above,,, otherwise it will open it inside the modal..

I hope its clear enough, please some help cause i m trying for ages to solve this..

Thank you in advance for reading this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A general if clause to check if a string starts with a specific word is:

```
<?php if(substr($item->getPrimaryLink()->getUrl(), 0, 10) == "index.php/") : ?>
...
<?php endif; ?>
```

Reference: [substr](http://php.net/substr)

Comment: emmanuel you rule ! it was eaxclty that i was looking for, substr worked like a charm,

Comment: marked as correct answer!!,, thank you very much for the effort

Answer (score 0):

Using an URL library like http://url.thephpleague.com/3.0/ should do the work exploding the URL between :

index.php/component/content/article

and the GET argument id.

Then you can simplify your code.